# How to create a project in Android Studio without the support library?

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library, build.gradle

I'm sorry if this is a stupid question but I'm new to Android development and for my first app, I don't have any plans to support devices running API 17 and lower so I wish to not use the support library. However, when I create a new project in Android Studio (even with no activity) I can still see

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
}
```

in my Gradle file.

How can I create a project without the support library? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the support library , removing the dependency from your `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
}
```

To set minSdk=17 you can use:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 22
    }
}
```